# vim emulator does not work properly in pycharm ipython notebook

Tags: pycharm, ipython

PyCharm community version 2016.3, when I enable Vim Emulator and open an Ipython Notebook, it just does not work. I believe it is very easy to duplicate, and I don't know if that is a bug for PyCharm or there are settings to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking submitted issues for Pycharm on the Jetbrains site reveals the following:

In a cell, insert mode is activated by default. Unfortunately, <kbd>Esc</kbd> is trapped by the IDE because it is needed for IDE actions. Fortunately, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as in the original VIM will cancel insert mode and place you in "command line" mode.